# Android app compatibility broken on play store after appcompat update

Tags: android, compatibility, android-appcompat

I've updated my app using appcompat library and now many devices are not compatible with my app. I've not changed anything in manifest.

Here what i have in manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="10"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"/>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

Here is what developers console says to me:

```
Previously active APKs supported more devices than those in the draft configuration.      
Some devices will not receive upgrades.
Devices currently running version 15 are no longer supported by the current configuration. Such devices will not receive upgrades. 
API levels in range 10+ and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.CAMERA, android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.location.GPS, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT] but excluding any of [android.hardware.camera.AUTOFOCUS]

Devices currently running version 14 are no longer supported by the current configuration. Such devices will not receive upgrades. 
API levels in range 10+ and 
Screen layouts containing any of [small, normal, large, xlarge] and 
Features containing all of [android.hardware.TOUCHSCREEN, android.hardware.screen.PORTRAIT] but excluding any of [android.hardware.CAMERA, android.hardware.LOCATION, android.hardware.TELEPHONY, android.hardware.location.GPS]
```

Can someone explain what console is talking about and suggest something to do to return compatibility?

Comment: You should use the latest version(18) as the `targetSDKVersion`.

Comment: done. the same result. I've also added  
    <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:xlargeScreens="false"
    android:anyDensity="true" />
app is still not compatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, from the google support feedback:

> In this case, your app is not compatible due to a conflict with the
>   following permissions/features: android.hardware.camera.autofocus. For
>   more information...

i'm really appreciate their help and it was fast enough

But! This line was there last 2 years. And right now after i've used appcompat to update the project, google decide to restrict it. The app absolutely don't care about autofocus. And I don't know who wrote this line before me.

I've read all the similar questions here and tried almost all, but in my case i think only support can help me.